# Better filtering/sorting by tag of the questions page?

Tags: feature-request

When I add "ignored tags" to my profile, it greys questions out but leaves them in the flow.  I don't know whether this is something that simply hasn't propegated from stackoverflow.com yet or something, but this behavior seems to be different (and less useful) than what happens on SO (it doesn't even seem to show questions that are on the ignored tag list).

What's the deal there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your profile page, under the `prefs` tab, there is your list of favorite and ignored tags. There's a checkbox beneath the ignored tags labeled `hide ignored tags`. If you check it, then it will hide your ignored tags in the same way that you see on Stack Overflow.